# Angular 9 materialize css modal not recognizing methods

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

I have an angular 9 application and I'm using the materialize-css 1.0 lib to add a modal into my application, I can instantiate/open the modal without any problems, but I have a confirm and close button inside my modal but it doesn't seem to recognize any of my methods on my .ts file.

```
file.component.ts

@ViewChild('modal', { static: false }) modalElement: ElementRef;
myModal = null;

...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myModal = new M.Modal(this.modalElement.nativeElement, {});
}

openModal() {
   this.myModal.open();
}

closeModal() {
   this.myModal.close();
}

confirmModal() {
   ...some logic
}
```

```
file.component.html

<div id="modal" class="modal" #myModal>
   ...
   <button onclick="confirmModal()">confirm</button>
</div>
```

When my modal is open and I click on the cofirm button inside the modal, I get reference error:

> confirmModal is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong notation `onclick`, it's `(click)`.